# Colloquial/slang term for "curious girl"

Tags: colloquial

What would be a colloquial or slang term to designate a very curious, indiscreet girl?
It would eventually be used as a fiction character nickname ("La Curiosa" is too bland).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141723/discussion-on-question-by-jeanb-colloquial-slang-term-for-curious-girl).

Comment: impicciona, ficcanaso but not related girls only. I'm sure there are also regional ones

Answer (score 1):

Non conosco una parola specifica per ragazza, ma forse "invadente", "pettegola" o "ficcanaso".